# Finding breaking changes when upgrading to PHP 8

Tags: php, php-8

PHP 8.0 introduces a number of changes that can break existing code. For example [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) now throws an exception instead of returning a boolean when given a null argument. This change is not mentioned in the [Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) document. Is there tool or method to systematically analyze an existing PHP code base to flag potential breaking changes caused by upgrading to the PHP 8 engine?

Comment: https://php.watch/versions/8.0 is useful, and mentions this change - https://php.watch/versions/8.0#error-handling specifically.

Comment: To avoid the exception i use count($data ?? ''); So it suppress as null if it fails. Comparing php8 vs php7. php 8 wins in performance.

Comment: That specific function has been throwing a warning [since 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types) for null, and has never returned a boolean. But I do agree that I can’t find a mention of the warning being promoted to a TypeError in the documentation. There was [an attempt at an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coercion_consistency) to reduce the impact for functions that previously “worked” with null, but `count` was not targeted. The fix is static analysis and watching the logs unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

[Rector](https://getrector.org/blog/2020/11/30/smooth-upgrade-to-php-8-in-diffs) can help to upgrade code from earlier versions (and downgrade, if required). For the issue of `count()`, there is the [IsCountableRector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#iscountablerector), which will add an `is_countable($var)` check ahead of the use of problematic variables within the `count()`.

Using a 'set' of rules is usually easier, such as:
`$containerConfigurator->import(LevelSetList::UP_TO_PHP_80);`